# $firebaseUtils.toJSON throwing Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I'm extending a really basic $firebaseObject with a toJSON function which looks exactly like:

```
toJSON: function() {
  var data = $firebaseUtils.toJSON(this);
  return data;
}
```

I oriented myself after the [gist of Katowulf](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/1924bab5795a56effc19) but I keep getting this error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.isObject (angular.js:590)
    at Object.toJSON (angularfire.min.js:1)
    at a.toJSON (tournament.js:375)
    at Object.toJSON (angularfire.min.js:1)
    at a.toJSON (tournament.js:375)
    at Object.toJSON (angularfire.min.js:1)
    at a.toJSON (tournament.js:375)
    at Object.toJSON (angularfire.min.js:1)
    at a.toJSON (tournament.js:375)
    at Object.toJSON (angularfire.min.js:1)
```

When I took a deeper look, with console.trace(), it shows that my toJSON function calls itself again and again which creates an infinite loop.

It starts from:

```
toJSON  @   tournament.js:375
toJSON  @   angularfire.min.js:1
...
```

and goes on like:

```
toJSON  @   tournament.js:375
toJSON  @   angularfire.min.js:1
toJSON  @   tournament.js:376
toJSON  @   angularfire.min.js:1
...
```

up to:

```
toJSON  @   tournament.js:375
toJSON  @   angularfire.min.js:1
toJSON  @   tournament.js:376
toJSON  @   angularfire.min.js:1
toJSON  @   tournament.js:376
toJSON  @   angularfire.min.js:1
toJSON  @   tournament.js:376
toJSON  @   angularfire.min.js:1
toJSON  @   tournament.js:376
toJSON  @   angularfire.min.js:1
toJSON  @   tournament.js:376
toJSON  @   angularfire.min.js:1
toJSON  @   tournament.js:376
toJSON  @   angularfire.min.js:1
toJSON  @   tournament.js:376
toJSON  @   angularfire.min.js:1
...
```

When removing toJSON it works fine, but I really need to do some work before saving to firebase.

Edit: After taking a closer look into the $firebaseUtils.toJSON() source code, I see why I get an infinite loop here, but I wonder how kato's version works?

Comment: It sounds like you have a cyclical reference in the object upon which you are calling `toJSON`.

Comment: Well `$firebaseUtils.toJSON()` checks if my factory has a function called `toJSON` (which it has) and this function executes `$firebaseUtils.toJSON()` again which checks it again and there starts the cycle.